# identifying type of an authenticated user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, authentication, jwt

I'm building an app that both regular users and admins will have access to. You get access to it after passing through authentication.

Once authenticated, I need to check what type of user the current user is. Is he/she a regular user or an admin? Based on this, certain things will be rendered, or not.

I'm using Node, React, and MongoDB. How could I go about doing this? Can this be achieved using JSON Web Tokens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the user authenticates, you will presumably be looking them up in some sort of user database.  When you find them in the database, you can read from the database whether they have administrative privileges or not.  How exactly you do that depends upon how you're storing your data.  It could be as simple as a boolean flag on the user.

Once you know that the user has successfully authenticated, a web app would typically establish a server-side user session.  That involves setting an encrypted session cookie on the browser and then linking that session cookie to a session object on the server that you create.  That session object can itself be stored in a database or can be held in memory (depending upon deployment needs).  Once you see the user has administrative privileges, you can set a property in the session object that indicates this user has those privileges.  Future rendering can use that flag to decide what to put in the page.

A JSON web token can be used instead of the cookie, but that is not typically the preferred way of doing a web application because the browser manages the cookie for you automatically, but you'd have to manage the JSON web token yourself in your own app code.  You could also put a JSON web token in the cookie, though that is not required.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. A follow up question... how would you go about producing an encrypted session cookie? Is this cookie produced in the server and then passed to the browser? If that's the case, would you use a package to do this? (I'm using npm)

Comment: @JaySeeCode - If you use something like [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) as your session manager, then the encrypted session cookie is taken care of for you automatically.  You may also want to use [passport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport) with that for the auth.

Comment: Thank you again! :)